# Need to repeat toast after every 10 sec using Service?

Tags: android, service

**I need to repeat Toast after every 10 second. How can I do this thing.**

**Below I add a simple code of the Service Class :**

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Repeat After 10 Sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I have done this using CountDownTimer and Service

here is sample code.

In service

```
MyTimer timer;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Repeat After 10 Sec", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   timer = new MyTimer(200000, 10000);
}
```

countdowntimer class

```
class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    // constructor for timer class
    public MyTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }

    // this method called when timer is finished
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

        timer.start();
    }

    // this method is called for every iteration of time interval
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //display toast here
        Toast.makeText(context, "YOUR MESSAGE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the rly , I want to do this one using Thread and Handler ... Can you tell me about this

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207612/android-execute-code-in-regular-intervals

Comment: thats is what i am finding ... Thanks for the help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36979/discussion-between-ketan-and-a-m)