# Android Schedule SMS in given Specific time

Tags: android

Im new to android development and Im developing an app which schedule the sms to send with given specific time. Sending time has been saved in SQLLITE DB. IF the time has been reach to the DB time SMS should be sent. 
I can achieve the SMS sending part but not to check the time.

I know that i need to use Android AlarmManager and i know how to use it.

My problem is to get the time from DB and check the check with Device time.(Kind of service)

Comment: Use android alarm manager to send an event to your app for specific time and send the sms on your required time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes need to use AlarmManager, but I think it would not be a good approach to keep looking database to check how many messages are pending to send and weather it has got the time to send or not.

Defiantly you need to write a background [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for that, But do you think its a good approach?

- Will this service keep looking in db all the time? (Too much resource
  consuming)
- What period will you set if you want to run service
  periodically? (Compromise on time accuracy of sending)

Its AlarmManager which is most appropriate for this. Just initialize a alarm when you are making entry in db right now. Make you alarm to be RTC_WAKEUP, so that it can send message even the phone is powered off. And every thing will be handled by android itself.

Yes can use database still to have record of all the messages sent by you application, pending to sent, sent successfully, failed etc. Means make entry with messages and its status in db, and just update on respective events like update it to successfully sent when alarm triggered.

Long story, but hope this helps...

Comment: Hi Ali, I have done the job as you suggested. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you should accept this answer to that other can get help form it and to improve you ratings as well...

Comment: Ali, How can I accept this answer. Please help me.. Im new to Stackoverflow...

Comment: Accepting the answer indicates correct/best answer among all. In this way, so other people (who got through similar problem like you asked) can use this answer too. You can see the tick/check mark on the top left of this answer, right under the answer rating. Hover your mouse and you will see the tool tip describing the event.

Comment: or see that http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139

Comment: Gud work, and wellcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

First of all i would suggest Alarm Manager is too much heavy to use. 
I would prefer you to write a synchronous class using mutithreading which trigger your task

> The postdelay option does the trick of alarm manager.

Its your choice to make that synchronous class a service one.

I came across few examples regarding this synchronous classes for android one of them is

[Android: execute code in regular intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207612/android-execute-code-in-regular-intervals)

The accepted answer will help you how to write an syn class which triggers your need.

Its now easy for you to place your db value in postdelay function for dynamic delays.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I used the alarm Manager to complete the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use GCM Intent Service. It is used to run a particular code even when your app is idle or in background.
In that class, write a handler or a timer, having your code.
This approach you can try or look into it