# How to stop TimerTask already in execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

[How to stop a running TimerTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100935/how-to-stop-a-running-timertask)

I have gone through the above link and my problem didn't solve completely.

We can stop a Timer, by calling `timerObj.cancel()`. The documentation of `cancel` method clearly says:

> Cancels the {@code Timer} and all scheduled tasks. **If there is a
>    currently running task it is not affected**. No more tasks may be scheduled on this {@code Timer}. Subsequent calls do nothing

So my question/concern here is,

If lot of TimerTasks were scheduled under a `timer`, How could we stop all of them **even If they are executing their respective `run` methods**? Is there a way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Of course there is - grab the tasks and kill them -

Comment: What do you mean by 'grad the tasks' and how to kill them?

Comment: ok show some nice code - you go with your logic and set up the conditions to kill - I dont see no code - each task has a run so go in there and setup conditions

Comment: Looks like someone already have the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045360/how-to-stop-the-timer-thread

Comment: if you want a nice premade command from Big Daddy no candy for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design the run method so that it can determine for itself when to terminate, for example by polling the state of an [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

Even if you were to [find the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3018672/7098259) running the TimerTask, calling stop() or similar methods upon the thread would be [inherently unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504140/thread-stop-deprecated).